# Dummies guide to making dropzone.js work?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to implement a drag-n-drop fileupload to my website and found a piece of java called Dropzone.js, it holds everything i need . . . i just have no idea of how to use it!

So far I've been programming only in razor `ASP.NET (c#)` / `HTML` / `CSS`, but so far no javascript / jquery.

It's razor webpages, so no mvc.

Due to my current lack of knowledge in java, i apologize in advance but i'm stuck !!

What i'd like to know is:

I'f i've understood things correct, i should not modify Dropzone.js directly, i should use it as a library and integrate it in my other scripts, e.g. in another .js file. Correct?

Any help in this will be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Daniel A. Rischel

.. Edited as per requested.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider separating your question into three questions (or better yet: remove two of the questions). Your first question can be answered with a simple yes or no, so is a proper question to ask. Your two other questions violate the guidelines of SO because they ask for recommendations of a library or tutorial. If you leave them there, your question will most likely be closed as off-topic.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind from now on. Thank you. I've removed the troublesome parts of my question(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're wrong somewhat. It might not be related to the question but please note these scripts are JavaScript  and

```
java != javascript
```

Got the point? :) Please try to note this in future. Also, Java code cannot be added to these server-side language, because java itself is a language. You can use JavaScript or its library (jQuery) and create some plugins.

> I'f i've understood things correct, i should not modify Dropzone.js directly, i should use it as a library and integrate it in my other scripts, e.g. in another .js file. Correct?

True, you need to link this plugin `dropzone.js` to the site using

```
<script href="/link/to/dropzone.js"></script>
```

Then you'll use this script on the whole of the page where it is linked.

And you should never edit the source code of a plugin, untill or unless you know what you're doing. Because you might mess up with the code.

> I'd really like to see some source code examples of what a single file drag-n-drop fileupload form would look like. I've googled extensively but not found something i can use yet.

Did you try to read their documentations? They have a good code explaination on the default (main) page of their website too. And really it depends on just the way you style it. Its just a plugin, you  will need to add your own CSS code to style the form. This plugin won't style the form for you, all it will do is to handle the upload events and get back with the result. So, which means that form creation and elements is all upto you!

> If there is a dummies tutorial in making this work, i'd really like to be pointed in the right direction!

There is no perfect answer to provide you with, however I will provide you with some basics

http://www.javascriptoo.com/dropzone-js

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropzone.js?sort=newest&pageSize=15 (stackoverflow tag)

In the second link, you can go and see what are the very basic of the issues that are handled with what code. Easy methods will be hanlded by you! You'll need some guidance in just the hard jobs. Good luck for that!

My suggestion for you is to first undertand and learn jQuery, then learn how to make ajax calls. After that you'll know how to create and handle the events. The basic code will be

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function () { // change in value
   // send the file via ajax 
}
```

http://jquery.com

This method will be best as you will know what code you're using and what it will do. Using plugin is easy method then this one. But my preference is with the second one; creating your own plugin.